# Unable to use sql server user name and password

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection-string, instance

my user name is Work/Sainath and password is empty and i use windows authentication to login. My server name is '.' and when i enter this as connection string in visual studio web form i get an error for the / behind sainath ![enter image description here][1]

please help as i'm not able to connect and tired of this.I tried changing in security but not not highlighted and not able to change the fields

error that i get for connection string(`SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=.,User id=Sainath,Password=,Database=Work");`)

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Comment: how are you passing connection in your web form please provide the related code

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=.,User id=Sainath,Password=,Database=Work");

Comment: it doesn't describe / in your question ? and you should add your code and error code in question by editing the question

Comment: sorry its my first time raising a bug,i have edited the questions as well let me know the solution

Comment: getting this error now 
Login failed for user 'Sainath'.I have a screenshot but not able to upload it here